# Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888) Can't create callback thread. Perhaps too many simultaneous pigpio connections

Tags: raspbian, python, python-3, pigpio, dht22

Have connected DHT11 to Rpi4.

VCC--pin 1

datapin--gpio4

Ground pin--pin 6

It works fine fine but after giving the result for few times then I get this error.
New to pigpio please do help me figure out what's wrong

```
import time
from pigpio_dht import DHT11, DHT22
while True:
        gpio = 4 # BCM Numbering

        sensor = DHT11(gpio)
#sensor = DHT22(gpio)

        result = sensor.read()

        temperature=([value for value in result.values()][0])
        print(temperature)

        humidity=([value for value in result.values()][2])
        print(humidity)
        time.sleep(10)
```

Output:

```
28
46

28
46

28
46

28
46

28
46
```

and then I get the following:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Can't create callback thread.
Perhaps too many simultaneous pigpio connections.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dht8.py", line 9, in <module>
    sensor = DHT11(gpio)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pigpio_dht/dht11.py", line 24, in __init__
    super(DHT11, self).__init__(gpio, pi=pi, timeout_secs=timeout_secs, use_internal_pullup=True, max_read_rate_secs=1, datum_byte_count=1)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pigpio_dht/dhtxx.py", line 47, in __init__
    self._pi.set_pull_up_down(gpio, pigpio.PUD_UP)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1385, in set_pull_up_down
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_PUD, gpio, pud))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 993, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are invoking multiple simultaneous connections to the pigpio daemon.

Move the DHT creation outside the loop.  E.g. try

```py
import time
from pigpio_dht import DHT11, DHT22

gpio = 4 # BCM Numbering

sensor = DHT11(gpio)
#sensor = DHT22(gpio)

while True:

        result = sensor.read()

        temperature=(
           [value for value in result.values()][0])
        print(temperature)

        humidity=(
           [value for value in result.values()][2])
        print(humidity)

        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: You are right.. it's working fine now.. thank you